# WCF Endpoint does not use provided Https binding

Tags: wcf, reflection, configuration, endpoint

I'm calling an external WCF service and am getting the following error message.  "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.  Parameter name: via"

here are the config sections pertaining to the service:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://www.odfl.com:443/wsRate_v4/RateService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RatePortBinding" contract="OdflRateService.RateDelegate" name="RatePort" />
</client>
```

and the binding Section:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="RatePortBinding">
         <security mode="Transport" />
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The assembly is calling the service is loaded into the app through reflection and the configuration values are in the main app web config.  I don't know if this makes any difference but thought i should mention it.

Thanks!

Comment: I hope [this][1] link will help. Transport forces https.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617751/web-service-error-the-provided-uri-scheme-http-is-invalid-expected-https

Comment: that's just it i want it in https and not http, for some reason this is creating the service in http